# Where do these 1k threads come from

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

I am trying to create a application that multi threaded downloads images from a website, as a introduction into threading. (never used threading properly before)

But currently it seems to create 1000+ threads and I am not sure where they are coming from.

I first queue a thread into a thread pool, for starters i only have 1 job in the jobs array

```
foreach (Job j in Jobs)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Download, j);
}
```

Which starts the void `Download(object obj)` on a new thread where it loops through a certain amount of pages (images needed / 42 images per page)

```
for (var i = 0; i < pages; i++)
{
    var downloadLink = new System.Uri("http://www." + j.Provider.ToString() + "/index.php?page=post&s=list&tags=" + j.Tags + "&pid=" + i * 42);

    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(downloadLink);
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                response = e.Result;  
                ProcessPage(response, false, j);
            };
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            // Unity editor equivalent of console.writeline
            Debug.Log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

correct me if I am wrong, the next void gets called on the same thread

```
void ProcessPage(string response, bool secondPass, Job j)
{
    var wc = new WebClient();
    LinkItem[] linkResponse = LinkFinder.Find(response).ToArray();

    foreach (LinkItem i in linkResponse)
    {
        if (secondPass)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Href))
                continue;
            else if (i.Href.Contains("http://loreipsum."))
            {
                if (DownloadImage(i.Href, ID(i.Href)))
                    j.Downloaded++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (i.Href.Contains(";id="))
            {
                var alterResponse = wc.DownloadString("http://www." + j.Provider.ToString() + "/index.php?page=post&s=view&id=" + ID(i.Href));
                ProcessPage(alterResponse, true, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally passes on to the last function and downloads the actual image

```
bool DownloadImage(string target, int id)
{
    var url = new System.Uri(target);
    var fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(url.AbsolutePath);
    var ext = fi.Extension;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ext))
    {
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                wc.DownloadFileAsync(url, id + ext);
                return true;
            }
            catch(System.Exception e)
            {
                if (DEBUG) Debug.Log(e);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Returned Without a extension: " + url + " || " + fi.FullName);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am not sure how I am starting this many threads, but would love to know.

**Edit**

The goal of this program is to download the different job in jobs at the same time (max of 5) each downloading a maximum of 42 images at the time.

so a maximum of 210 images can/should be downloaded maximum at all times.

Comment: you run async operation inside another thread. why don't just use async and that is. ? what benefits does threading provides to you, in this case ?

Comment: @Tigran Probably none, just trying to get the hang of threading, would it make more sense to use the blocking call instead of the async call then in a threading situation?

Comment: If you are using async, don't use threading. use threads if you are going to control the concurrency workload, so span as many threads as required and not more.

Comment: VS: Debug->Windows->Threads. It should explain why you have so many threads. (Also have no idea why you have post tagged with unity3d - maybe there is something special about it).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Making it in the unity engine (game engine), it has limited capabilities over usual .net.

Comment: @MXD: it depends on how many downloads you have to do. and how fast they execute. having multiple threads doing something in parallel, when on host machine you don;t have necessary amount of hardware parallelism supported, is not necessary  good idea. you have to try different amount to see which one fits better your needs.

Comment: @Tigran Added some more detail to better specify the ultimate goal of the program.

Comment: so you can try to start 5 threads, each of them start downloading a stack of images and see how that works out for you.

Comment: @Tigran if it's unity3d code, it's stuck with .NET 2.0

Comment: you still can create threads, or use async programming models.

Comment: @MaxYankov .NET 2.0/3.5

Comment: @MXD thanks for correction, I'm just used to 2.0 subset compatibility level.

Comment: @MXD how do you measure amount of threads, exactly? And what system are you running on?

Comment: @MaxYankov source control, windows 7 64 bit,

Comment: What do you mean by "source control" — you measure the amount of threads running in your system with source control? This doesn't make sense. I'm asking, because if you run the editor and get a lot of threads in a task manager, it wouldn't be a clean result, and I would advise you to try a standalone build.

Comment: @MaxYankov It aint a clean view, But as i set the task amount to 1k, I assume it created a thread for each of the images. Thats atleast the hunch im going on right now

Comment: What you're saying is very unclear, you said "it seems to create 1000+ threads", why are you assuming that? Where are you seeing those 1000 threads?

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Traced it down, I had the download target set to 1000 files, which all started at the same time. All on their own webclient starting the async download, leading to a crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, how did you measure the thread count? Why do you think that you have thousand of them in your application? You are using the `ThreadPool`, so you don't create them by yourself, and the `ThreadPool` wouldn't create such great amount of them for it's needs.

Second, you are mixing synchronious and asynchronious operations in your code. As you can't use `TPL` and `async/await`, let's go through you code and count the `unit-of-works` you are creating, so you can minimize them. After you do this, the number of queued items in `ThreadPool` will decrease and your application will gain performance you need.

1. You don't set the [`SetMaxThreads`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.80).aspx) method in your application, so, [according the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.80).aspx):

   > **Maximum Number of Thread Pool Threads**
   >   The number of operations that can be queued to the thread pool is limited  only by available memory; 
   >   however, the thread pool limits the number of threads that can be
   >   active in the process simultaneously. **By default, the limit is 25
   >   worker threads per CPU and 1,000 I/O completion threads.**

   So you must set the maximum to the `5`.
2. I can't find a place in your code where you check the `42` images per Job, you are only incrementing the value in `ProcessPage` method.
3. Check the `ManagedThreadId` for the handle of `WebClient.DownloadStringCompleted` - does it execute in different thread or not.
4. You are adding the new item in `ThreadPool` queue, why are you using the asynchronious operation for Downloading? Use a [synchronious overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200(v=vs.80).aspx), like this:

   ```
   ProcessPage(wc.DownloadString(downloadLink), false, j);
   ```

   This will not create another one item in `ThreadPool` queue, and you wouldn't have a sinchronisation context switch here.
5. In `ProcessPage` your `wc` variable doesn't being garbage collected, so you aren't freeing all your resourses here. Add `using` statement here:

   ```
   void ProcessPage(string response, bool secondPass, Job j)
   {
       using (var wc = new WebClient())
       {
           LinkItem[] linkResponse = LinkFinder.Find(response).ToArray();

           foreach (LinkItem i in linkResponse)
           {
               if (secondPass)
               {
                   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Href))
                       continue;
                   else if (i.Href.Contains("http://loreipsum."))
                   {
                       if (DownloadImage(i.Href, ID(i.Href)))
                           j.Downloaded++;
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   if (i.Href.Contains(";id="))
                   {
                       var alterResponse = wc.DownloadString("http://www." + j.Provider.ToString() + "/index.php?page=post&s=view&id=" + ID(i.Href));
                       ProcessPage(alterResponse, true, j);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. In `DownloadImage` method you also use the asynchronious load. This also adds item in `ThreadPoll` queue, and I think that you can avoid this, and use [synchronious overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile(v=vs.80).aspx) too:

   ```
   wc.DownloadFile(url, id + ext);
   return true;
   ```

So, in general, avoid the context-switching operations and dispose your resources properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your wc WebClinet will go out of scope and be randomly garbage collected before the async callback.   Also on all async calls you have to allow for immediate return and the actual delegated function return.  So processPage will have to be in two places.   Also the j in the original loop may be going out of scope depending on where Download in the original loop is declared.